# Show only polyline

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am working on an activity tracker, at the end of the activity I have a map where I draw the polyline of the users route, I want to show only the polyline or at least draw a shadow in the map like Nike+Run does, anyone know if that's possible?, I already searched but I couldn't find out how to do it.

Edit:
Something like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is MKPolyline. Here is the documentation https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkpolyline and this tutorial might be helpful to implement http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-draw-an-mkpolyline-on-a-map-view/. Its in Obj C should be easy enough reimplement in Swift.

Comment: thanks but i already have the polyline, what i need is to change the style of the map, for example: make it purple, or hide the map and only show the polyline